# C# Form- How get date as a string

Tags: c#, forms, date

I want set a string variable `date` as the current system date preferably in "22February2012" format.

So something like:

```
string date = [code to get gate];
```

Thanks

Comment: `preferably`? So, you are open to any solution?

Comment: @Oliverguy please show more effort than that..this is not a difficult task. Google DataTime object and how you can get at LongDate ShortDate etc....

Comment: @MethodMan Sorry if this is an easy question, I did google it and I couldn't find any clear information. Maybe I just didn't look in the right places and would be glade to except any recommendations on places to get information. Also, I didn't even know what to do, as I said I'm new to C# and programing in general. Therefor I wouldn't have known to search DateTime. Lastly, why did you even comment that? If you don't think you need to answer a "stupid" question, then move along to the next one, don't waste your time commenting on how "easy" it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DateTime.Now` for getting current system date and use [`DateTime.ToString(string format)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for converting it to equivalent string representation with the specified format which must be `ddMMMMyyyy` for your case:

```
string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMMMyyyy");
```

Comment: your answer would yield a month of `05Mar2015` you need to have something like the following 
`var strDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMMMyyyy"); yields 05March2015`